# Disable layout autoresize in layout.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, primefaces

I've got an application made using primefaces which in turn uses the [jquery ui layout plugin](http://layout.jquery-dev.com/index.cfm) to change the size of four divs (north, south, west and center) when you resize the browser window.

I'm not allowed to remove the script myself as it's part of the application so I need a way to disable this resize functionality after the page has loaded.

If there's a way to unset the script after it's loaded that would work fine as I don't need it on this particular page.

Here's what I've got so far without much luck

```
function InitializeLayout(sElement) {
    var options = {
        resizeWithWindow: false,
        resizable: false,   
        closable:  false,   
        initPanes:  false,   
        west__resizable: false,   
        west__closable:  false,
        defaults : {
            autoResize: false
        },
        west : {
            autoResize: false
        }
    };
    oLayout = $(sElement).layout(options);

    console.log(oLayout.state);
}


jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    InitializeLayout("#layout-body");
});
```

https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/source/browse/primefaces/trunk/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/primefaces/layout/layout.js?r=7990

Comment: There must be a reason but why don't you just set `resizable="false"` on the layout units? Or is it in a template?

Comment: @Kukeltje It is in a template so I can't edit the html files. Any changes I make can only be done through css and js files.